# Handling bad requests in aiohttp

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to figure out a way to handle bad requests from an API within an asynchronous function using aiohttp. This is what I've got for testing:

```
async def fetch(session):
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/status/404'
    async with session.request('GET', url) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            try:
                r = await response.json()
                return r
            except ValueError:
                return
        else:
            return None

async def fetch_all(project_list):
    output = []
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(session, project)) for project in project_list]
        for future in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
            output += future
    return output

def get_data(project_list):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_all(project_list))
    output = loop.run_until_complete(futures)
    return output
```

In this example, `project_list` is just a list of integers.

In this instance, `fetch()` should return none since the response will undoubtedly be 404. The problem arises in `fetch_all()` where I tell it to `+=` future. I get a `TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not iterable.` Basically I'd like this to return nothing and in this case, `+=` nothing to that list. In a perfect world I'd receive a proper json response every time, but I'd like to account for a random instance wherein I receive a bad response from the server.

From what I've read, `@asyncio.coroutine` would return None but `async` values have to be `awaited` if I'm understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you don't need to wrap task in ensure_future if you want to use gather. Second, you are trying to add fetch tasks with 2 arguments: session and project, but you have only session in your fetch function definition. And one more thing you can change is removing the loop where you are iterating through gather result because it already gives you the output you want to return.
Code will be like that:

```
async def fetch(session, project):
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/status/404'
    async with session.request('GET', url) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            try:
                return await response.json()

            except ValueError:
                pass

        return None

async def fetch_all(project_list):
    output = []
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [fetch(session, project) for project in project_list]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def get_data(project_list):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    output = loop.run_until_complete(futures)
    return output
```

As for advice: use ensure_future only if you want to run coroutine instantly but the result will be needed only in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure this is the best way to do it but I put this together and it worked. If anyone can correct me, please do.

```
async def fetch_all(project_list):
    output = []
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(session, project)) for project in project_list]
        for future in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
            if future is not None: #Check if the future is None before adding it
                output += future
    return output
```